# Should I use past perfect tense in the sentence?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

past simple

> He went for a week, so he took only hand luggage

past perfect

> He went for a week, so he had taken only hand luggage *(the first action- had taken luggage; the second one- went)*

Comment: It's meaningless to talk about which "came first" out of *going for a week* and *taking hand luggage*. The choice of simple past or past perfect really depends on the full narrative context. Is it necessary to emphasise that going with only hand luggage *preceded* whatever that narrative is primarily focused on? If so, you might consider *He **had gone** for a week...*, but as a general rule you probably want to avoid Past Perfect if possible. It's not as necessary as many learners seem to think.

Comment: As an aside, *luggage* is a mass or non-count noun; you can't have "a luggage".  You could say "one piece of luggage", though.

Comment: We use the past perfect if we want to talk about things that happened before this time.

The last part: "*..., so he had taken only hand luggage*" happened before "*He went for a week,...*". 

So I think you can use:

"He went for a week, so he had taken only hand luggage"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He went for a week, so he took only hand luggage

is a perfectly good and understandable sentence.

Also perfectly acceptable are

> He *had gone* for a week, so he took only hand luggage.

if you use

> *had only taken* hand luggage.

it will have more of an emphasis meaning "he didn't take much luggage", and might be used as an explanation for contrast

> He *went* for a week, so he *had only taken* hand luggage *(and not his surfboard)*.

Eventhough "*had taken*" might be considered to occur before the "*went* for a week" usually understanding of the situation (one packs before one travels) does not make the distinction mandatory.